# Ghidra internal work

Tags: ghidra

I have a question about working with variables in Ghidra.
Often variables are being used with many different purposes.
I understood it is possible to overcome this issue with commit param.
Does anyone know how to work with this option?

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted to get over this issue you need to commit the variables to the function. You can do this simply by right clicking the variable and pressing "Split out as New Variable"